# Two iframes in row same height

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, iframe

I have that code for two columns with iframes:

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="jumbotron" style="background-color:rgba(0,0,0, 0.3);">
            <div class="row row-eq-height">
                <div class="col-md-9" style="padding-right:20px; border-right: 3px solid #ccc;">
                    <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9" style="border:2px solid #2c3e50;">
                        <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="xxxx"></iframe>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9" style="border:2px solid #2c3e50;">
                        <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="xxxxxx"></iframe>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Problem is that right iframe is very tiny, I want to have the same height as first iframe on second.
[image: aaa]

How can I set height of second iframe to be the same as height of first iframe?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you set the height of the right iframe? For example, `style="height:200px"`

Comment: What width should i set to make iframe big as possible in column?

Comment: Do you mean width or height? Could you explain?

Comment: Now i set height of div and iframe to 420px in two columns(height set for div(responsive 16by9 and iframe) but first column is 5px bigger.

Comment: It's not easy to say without viewing the code. Could you create a code snippet?